# Set form as Parent throw exception "Top-level control cannot be added to a control"

Tags: c#, forms, exception, parent

I want to access variables of a form from another form.  On clicking a button inside my Main form, I want to set my Main form as Parent, then bring up another form (child form) wherein I will access variables of the Main form.  My click handler is as follow:

```
private void btnSystem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form_EnterPassword EP = new Form_EnterPassword();
    EP.Parent = this;        //error: Top-level control cannot be added to a control
    EP.ShowDialog();
}
```

It compiles fine without any error.  However, when I run the Main form and click on the System button, it throws me an exception.  I do something similar in another code (not mine) with the same button click, and encounter no error (just with setting Main form as Parent).

What am I doing wrong?  Is there something in my Main code that cause this?

Comment: I have read around and found nothing that helps.  there are similar codes, which have the same Parent setting declaration.

Comment: the exception is thrown right when I set Parent.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Best way would be to use `EP.ShowDialog(this)` and later use `Owner` property.

Comment: I change to .ParentForm; it throws me this error:

Property or indexer 'System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.ParentForm' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Comment: True that. Forget about parents. Just use `Owner`.

Comment: It worked after EP.ShowDialog(this) summons the EP form, and I do this during the Load event of EP (child form): Copied_MySettings       = ((Form_Parent)this.Owner).MySettings.  However, I cannot access 'MySettings' from the Parent form after this event.  Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 10):

You need the `EP.TopLevel` property to be set to false. It will let you to set a parent to it.

[Further reading.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.toplevel.aspx)

In case you only want to access variables and controls of another form, then maybe you can reach it in other ways, not trough a Parent relationship.

Comment: EP.TopLevel = false  -->  it does not help.

Comment: I think this should've been accepted as the correct answer. It did the job for me. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

OK,
apparently the way to do it is to call

```
Form_Child.ShowDialog(this)
```

and then I can call

```
FromParent_aVariable = ((Form_Parent)this.Owner).aVariable;
```

or if I define aVariable in the namespace Properties then

```
FromParent_aVariable = NameSpace.Properties.Settings.Default.aVariable;
```

there are two ways.

Answer (score 0):

```
Form_EnterPassword EP = new Form_EnterPassword();
EP.MdiParent = this;       
EP.Show();
```

try this way, it helps for me. you need to set principalform as isMdicontainer = true at the form properties

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation recently.
I was attempting something similar but by controlling the Child Forms from a different class.

**Note(s):**
You're trying to set the Child Form(s) "TopMost" to something that does not allow it.

 In this case the "MdiContainer".

**To accomplish this:**

• Disable MainForm "isMdiContainer" property (its use is kind of obsolete anyway).

• Set the Form(s) TopMost properties to true.

• You should now be able to accomplish your feature.

**Code Example:**

```
/* On your Main Form Class */

private void btnSystem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Instantiate the Form_EnterPassword by passing the MainForm
    Form_EnterPassword EP = new Form_EnterPassword(this);
    EP.Show(); // No longer as modal Form to display in front.
}

/* Under your EnterPassword Form Class */

// Do not create a new Instance of MyMainForm.
// You want to use the same thread as your MainForm
private MyMainForm mainForm;

/* Constructor */
public Form_EnterPassword(MyMainForm form)
{
    mainForm = form;
    this.Owner = mainForm; // "this" refers to the: EnterPassword Form.
}
```

**Remarks:**
The only additional thing that you (may) have to do, (to achieve perfection) is to check the MainForm > WindowState; and create a code block to minimize or bring the Forms to their specific state.

**i.e:**

```
if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
{ /* Code to Minimize all the Child Forms. */ }

else { /* Code to bring all Forms to their "Normal" State */ }
```

Answer (score -1):

Writing this way, made the dialog display on the center of the parent form.

```
   Form_Child.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
   Form_Child.ShowDialog(this);
```